# Simulation of elliptical orbit of earth around the sun using python 3.8.3 and vpython 7

Tags: python, python-3.x, simulation, vpython

```
from vpython import *

Sun= sphere(pos=vector(0,0,0), radius=100, color=color.orange)
earth = sphere(pos=vector(-200,0,0), radius=10, texture=textures.earth, make_trail = True)
earthv = vector(0,0,6)

for i in range(1000):

    rate(100)
    earth.pos = earth.pos + earthv

    dist=(earth.length**2+earth.width**2+earth.height**2)**0.5
    RadialVector = (earth.pos - Sun.pos)/dist
    Fgrav= -10000*RadialVector/dist**2
    earthv = earthv + Fgrav
    earth.pos += earthv
    if dist<= Sun.radius:
        break
```

It doesn't create an orbit at all. I'm unable to find the issue. Someone please help with the issue.
Thanks!
[Here is the screenshot of what happens on running the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ocyQ.png)